# std::vector и emplace_back()

Tags: c++

Правильно ли я понимаю, что метод **std::vector::emplace_back()** вызывает конструктор, но не конструктор перемещения?

В документации сказано, что объект конструируется на месте, вызывая для объекта конструктор с заданными параметрами.

Проблема заключается в том, что **MinGW** почему-то не хочет вызывать мой конструктор с заданными параметрами, вместо этого он зовет конструктор перемещения, который для заданного объекта удален. Я никак не могу понять, в чем дело.

Может, это какой-то баг? Я уже явно давал методу **emplace_back** параметр типа **size_t**. И он все равно говорит, что невозможно вызвать конструктор перемещения...

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int i;
    A(const int _i) : i(_i){};
    A(const A &_a) = delete;
    A(A &&_a) = delete;
    A &operator=(const A &_a) = delete;
    A &operator=(A &&_a) = delete;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<A> vec;
    vec.reserve(100);
    vec.emplace_back(-1);
}
```

Comment: Сделайте минимальный пример, на котором это воспроизводится и выложите здесь. Также укажите версию компилятора.

Comment: И хорошо бы текстом, а не картинками. Поиск по картинкам не очень хорош ещё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `std::vector::emplace_back` действительно создает новый объект на месте, однако он может вызывать конструктор перемещения для уже существующих объектов когда емкости вектора перестает хватать и для хранения объектов выделяется новый массив.

Для хранения объекта в векторе он должен иметь копирующий или перемещающий конструктор.

Comment: Вот оно что, спасибо большое.